# Create a new table Error 91 when trying to use string

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to create a new table from a form. I need to have dynamic table name and dynamic field names. I have tried to change the strtablename to an object with no luck. I am getting an error 91. any help is appreciated.

```
Private Sub cmdNewTable_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim NewField As Field
Dim strNewTable As String
Dim objNewTable As Object
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim strFieldName As String
Dim FieldTyoe As String
strNewTable = InputBox("Enter Table Name")
If strNewTable = vbNullString Then GoTo Skip:

   'Create New Table
    Set tdf = db.CreateTableDef(strNewTable)

y = InputBox("Enter amount of fields to add")

For x = 1 To y
   With tdf
    strFieldName = InputBox("Enter field Name")
    strfieldType = InputBox("Enter Field Type 1-Text 2-Integer 3-Long 4-
Single 5-Double 6-Decimal 7-Date 8-Currency 9-Yes/No 10-Memo")
    If strfieldType = 1 Then strfieldType = "dbText"
    If strfieldType = 2 Then strfieldType = "dbInteger"
    If strfieldType = 3 Then strfieldType = "dbLong"
    If strfieldType = 4 Then strfieldType = "dbSingle"
    If strfieldType = 5 Then strfieldType = "dbDouble"
    If strfieldType = 6 Then strfieldType = "dbDecimal"
    If strfieldType = 7 Then strfieldType = "dbDate"
    If strfieldType = 8 Then strfieldType = "dbCurrency"
    If strfieldType = 9 Then strfieldType = "dbBoolean"
    If strfieldType = 10 Then strfieldType = "dbMemo"

    Debug.Print strFieldName
    Debug.Print strfieldType
    Stop
    .Fields.Append .CreateField(strFieldName, strfieldType)

End With
```

Comment: Why implement a procedure that routinely modifies db structure? I suspect non-normalized db. I inherited a db with such a procedure. Never used it and finally eliminated it. Only developers should modify db, not users.

Answer (score 0):

First check your declaration: `Dim FieldTyoe As String`

That's a typo. Make sure to use `Option Explicit`. Make it `Dim strfieldType As String`.

Then look at this: `If strfieldType = 1`

This is an illegal evaluation.

To fix, put the number in quotes:
`If strfieldType = "1"`

You end your `With` block, but I don't see `Next x` or `End Sub`. You need error handling here as well in case the user input is invalid. What if they use a reserved character or word?